# How to wait on tokio dynamic tasks concurrently (tasks spawn during runtime and depend on each other to proceed)

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I have a 3 stage pipeline function. The first task reads the file, the second task parser the file, the third task sends the result to the server. Second tasks which is called producers tokio::spawns one task for each chunk it received through the channel and I add each task to the vector. Similarly the third task called consumers tokio::spawns one task for each chunk it received from producer and sends the data to the server. So the tasks inside of producer taks get spawned dynamically, similarly for consumer task

```
pub async fn process_log_file_minio () -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let mut chunk_receiver;

    {
        let (chunk_sender, receiver_from_reader) = mpsc::channel(*CORE_NUM as usize);
        chunk_receiver = receiver_from_reader;

        file_reader = tokio::spawn(async move {


            let mut buffer_chunk = Vec::new();

            loop {
               // ...here is I read the file in chunks
                    if buffer_chunk.len() == chunk_capacity {
                       
                        match chunk_sender.send(buffer_chunk).await {
                            //handle
                        };
                 println!("reader sent the batch");
                        buffer_chunk = Vec::with_capacity(chunk_capacity);
                    }
                }


            }
            if !buffer_chunk.is_empty() {
                match chunk_sender.send(buffer_chunk).await {
                    Ok(()) => {
                    }
                    _ => {
                        println!("failed the last chunk from reader");
                    }
                };
               
            }
     
        });
    }
    let mut producer_vec = Vec::new();
    let mut receiver;
    let producers :tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>;
    { 
        let (sender, rcv) = mpsc::channel(*SENDER_CHANNEL_SIZE as usize);
        //let (sender, rcv) = oneshot::channel();
        receiver = rcv;
        producers = tokio::spawn(async move {
            while let Some(buffer_chunk) = chunk_receiver.recv().await {
                let batch_size = *BATCH_TO_SEND_NUM_OF_LINES as usize;
                let _producer = tokio::spawn(async move {
  
                    let mut batch = Vec::with_capacity(batch_size);
                    
                    for element in buffer_chunk {
                        let log_data = parse_common_log_entry(.....)
                
                        batch.push(log_data);
                        if batch.len() >= batch_size {
                            
                            sender_clone.send(batch).await 
                               
                            batch = Vec::with_capacity(batch_size);
                        }
                    }
                    if !batch.is_empty() {

                        sender_clone.send(batch).await 

                    }
                });
                producer_vec.push(_producer);
                if producer_vec.len() > *CORE_NUM as usize {
                    (_, _, producer_vec) = futures::future::select_all(producer_vec).await;
                } 
            }
        });
    } 
    
    let mut consumers_vec = Vec::new(); 
    // Start the consumers.

    let ind_name = INDEX_NAME.to_string();
    let consumers = tokio::spawn(async move {
        
        while let Some(batch_to_send) = receiver.recv().await {
            let _consumer = tokio::spawn(async move {
                println!("right after spawn");
                
                let response =   client_clone_new.send(batch_to_send).await;

            });
           
            consumers_vec.push(_consumer);
            if consumers_vec.len() == *SENDER_CHANNEL_SIZE as usize {
                (_, _, consumers_vec) = futures::future::select_all(consumers_vec).await;
            }    
        }
    });

   
    match tokio::join!(file_reader, consumers, producers) {
        (Ok(()), Ok(()), Ok(())) =>... //handle cases
    }

    
    Ok(())
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {

    let result = process_log_file_minio().await;
    match result {
        Ok(()) => println!("successfully retrieved and parsed the file"),
        Err(e) => println!("some issue has occured {e}"),
    }
   
    Ok(())
}
```

I tried to debug and came to the conclusion that for some reason some of hte consumer tasks do not finish and main exits. I have no idea why as it seems to me the main is awaiting the process_log_file_minio fn which in turn finishes only after all the tasks it spawned get finished.
but if I add "std::process::sleep" before Ok(()) in the main for several milliseconds, the consumer tasks get executed successfully which seems to be absurd to me.

I created a producer tasks to manage all the _producer tasks so that I can call tokio::join! becauase it does not accept the vector of futures.

Any suggestion on how to improve the performance would be appreciated, I scrolled the resources and can't find anyone doing something similar to my program, so it is hard to find anything

Comment: The example is far from working, so it's very hard to figure out what the answer would be, but I would suggest heavily simplifying this until it works. Write it to a file instead of a server, then remove the parsing step, then try doing it sequentially.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).